# It is possible to use response.json() outside page.on

Tags: jquery, json, promise, puppeteer

```
page.on('response', (response) => {
    if (response.url().endsWith(url)&&response.request()._method === method) {
        response.json()
    }
})
```

How to use  `response.json()` outside page.on for future steps, cause if you wrap that code in promise, all steps will stuck, because of loop inside page.on

Answer (score 0):

```
async getResponse(url, method, responseBody) {
        const page = this.helpers['Puppeteer'].page;
        page.on('response', async (response) => {
            if ((await response.url()).endsWith(url)&&response. _request._method === method) {
               responseBody.push(await response.json());
            }
        });
    }
```

just need to declcare a variable before getResonse and use it

let response = []
getResponse(url, method, response)